# REST API call using nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, api

I am new to node.js. Following is my GET request:

```
router.get('/EPODS/Product/:id?', function(req, res) {
  if(req.params.id){
     var inputIdObj={'ProductEBM.DataArea.Product.ProductGroupID': req.params.id};
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({
      "Error": "No input given Try give something or Check for the case sensitive in the input query fields"
    });
    res.end();
    return;
  }

  db.collection('Product').findOne(inputIdObj,function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("No record found for the given input");
        res.end("No record found for the input data- Please check again");
      } else {  
       res.send(doc);  
      }
    });
  });
```

I am receiving `null` value when I hit the request in POSTMAN but the query works in MONGODB.

Please Help!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to share more information like DB Schema etc to further understand this. Also try console.log just before db.collection to see what is inputIdObj

Comment: This is my json which I want to get with respect to product group ID {
 "_id":"ProductJson_23042018",
  "ProductEBM": {    
    "DataArea": {      
      "Product": {
    "ProductGroupID" : "p",
     "IsPersonalisationChargeable": "true",
                "ProductLaunchDate" : "2008-09-29"
  }}

Answer (score 0):

When you get the parameter of the GET request, you get the ID in a String format, which will not work if you use ObjectID. First, cast your param in ObjectID (you can import the object with `require('mongodb').ObjectID`) and so create: `new ObjectID(req.params.id)`